# Run sub before deletion in Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to run a sub before deleting something in a word document. 
Is this possible?

Comment: Depends on how you imagine that should work - Word can't read your mind, so you need to signal it, somehow... Without more detail your question can't be answered.

Comment: There are ways... depending on your programming proficiency some of them may be unrealistic. But if you are interested in capturing the deletion of specific document content, then putting it into a `.ContentControl` would be a useful starting place.